# When spraying off marsh mallow root, is the outer skin supposed to fall right off when washed?

Tags: roots

After digging Marsh mallow I was spraying it off, and noticed the skin came right off. is this normal for a healthy root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. You are probably using a high pressure hose.
(I don't usually peel marshmallow roots, but if the skin comes off, well, why not.)

Comment: Actually it's just the garden hose on the full setting that I'm using.